# How to run Yocto with really slow internet?

Tags: yocto

I am trying to build an image using the yocto for the raspberry pi. The only thing I find hindering is that I have real slow connection to the internet. So I am just trying to figure out if there is a way where I could simply download the packages needed and put it in my host so that it doesn't have to do fetch.

How can I do and achieve that??

Comment: Is it working, but slow, or is it not working?

Comment: working but really slow. It is almost two days and do_fetch process are still running

Comment: Had similar issues with personal computer used for the build. Then used a dedicated build server with higher configuration, it was much more faster. Also check that the URL used for particular fetch is active and try to fetch that source with the URL to make sure that the URL is working.

Comment: Checked. Those are working. But ETA shows anywhere between 4-9 hours

Comment: I feel like I have found the answer btw. I have access to broadband but not on the host I am using. So I will findout and make a list of all the URL, download them and then probably build locally. The procedure is given in the mega manual. Will answer when I run it successfully.